# I am trying to add members to a AD group based on a value in the "title" attribute

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add members to a AD group based on a value in the "title" attribute. I have about 30 different tiles i want to use. Is there a way to write the command witout 30 "OR" statements?

Thanks

```
Get-ADuser -filter {(title -eq "SECSCH") -or (title -eq "SEC12") -or (title -eq 
"LTOSEC") -or (title -eq "LTO12")} | %{Add-ADGroupMember "SDK test print color" 
$_.SamAccountName}
```

Also, for another group I would like All "custod" in title except at location "85c" and "42c" Below is where i am at.

```
Get-ADuser -filter {(title -eq "custod") -and (locationNumber -ne "85c") -or (title -eq 
"custod") -and (locationNumber -ne "42c")} | %{Add-ADGroupMember "SDK test print 
convert" $_.SamAccountName}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first issue you can create an array which contains your titles and browse it.

Example :

```
$Titles = "SECSCH","SEC12","LTOSEC","LTO12"

foreach($Title in $Titles){
    Get-ADuser -filter {title -eq $Title} | %{Add-ADGroupMember "SDK test print color" $_.SamAccountName} 
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer because you're getting AD to filter the objects, not returning everything and having to do the `Where-Object` clause on all of it.

Answer (score 0):

The `-Members` parameter can take an [array of ADPrincipal objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-members) so what you can do instead of using so many 'OR's in the Filter is using a `Where-Object` clause afterwards.

This will allow you to use operators like `-contains` or `-match`

```
$titles = "SECSCH","SEC12","LTOSEC","LTO12" # your 30+ titles here
$users  = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Title | Where-Object { $titles -contains $_.Title }
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "SDK test print color" -Members $users
```

As for your second code change the Filter to below

```
$filter = "Title -eq 'custod' -and (locationNumber -ne '85c' -and locationNumber -ne '42c')"
$users  = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties Title, locationNumber
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "SDK test print convert" -Members $users
```

Note: the property `locationNumber` is AFAIK not a standard attribute in AD. Is that a custom property in your organization or do you perhaps mean something else like `Division` or `EmployeeNumber` ?

Comment: Hi, Th first part works, Thanks. The second, I changed it a little, we have custom attribute identifying our organization I am trying not to show. Below is what Tried and getting an error.    $LocationColour = "customLocation -eq '00', '0' ,'1','01', '2', 02' -and (employeeType -ne 'student')"
$users  = Get-ADUser -Filter $LocationColour -Properties customLocation, employeeType 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "SDK test print convert" -Members $users

Comment: Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'customLocation -eq '00', '0' ,'1','01', '2', 02' -and (employeeType -ne 'student')' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: ' at position: '24'.

Comment: @lakeek You can't use Filter like that. With an array you need to do that like the first code, do use a `Where-Object` clause

Answer (score 0):

I provided a different answer to the first at the [other place it was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74857303/i-am-trying-to-add-members-to-a-ad-group-based-on-a-value-in-the-title-attribu/74858221), using `-Ldapfilter`, but I feel @Onyx's answer here is probably more intuitive if you're not so comfortable with that. It's efficient in that you're only getting the objects you need, not grabbing *every account* out of AD and throwing away most of them.

To be honest, doing `-Filter 'title -like "*"'` would be better than nothing if you MUST use a `Where` clause.

For the second question (as described in the comments), the same applies with maybe building an LDAPfilter or @Onyx's method of creating an array for your `customlocations` and doing a `Foreach` through those.

Or again, at the very least, do `-Filter '(employeeType -ne "student") -and (CustomLocation -like "*")'`  before the `Where`.