# I am trying to add members to a AD group based on a value in the "title" attribute

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add members to a AD group based on a value in the "title" attribute. I have about 30 different titles I want to use. Is there a way to write the command without 30 "OR" statements?

Thanks

```
Get-ADuser -filter {(title -eq "SECSCH") -or (title -eq "SEC12") -or (title -eq 
"LTOSEC") -or (title -eq "LTO12")} | %{Add-ADGroupMember "SDK test print color" 
$_.SamAccountName}
```

Also, for another group I would like All "custod" in title except if their "location" attribute is "85c" or location "42c" Below is where i am at.

```
Get-ADuser -filter {(title -eq "custod") -and (locationNumber -ne "85c") -or (title -eq 
"custod") -and (locationNumber -ne "42c")} | %{Add-ADGroupMember "SDK test print 
convert" $_.SamAccountName}
```

Comment: Why asking the same question twice? [I am trying to add members to a AD group based on a value in the "title" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856045/i-am-trying-to-add-members-to-a-ad-group-based-on-a-value-in-the-title-attribu)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -in to specify list of values to compare with the title attribute

Here's an example :

```
$titles = "SECSCH", "SEC12", "LTOSEC", "LTO12"
Get-ADUser -Filter {title -in $titles} | ForEach-Object {
    Add-ADGroupMember "SDK test print color" $_.SamAccountName
}
```

on the same strategy, you can exclude locations with operator -notin

```
$excludedLocations = "85c", "42c"
Get-ADUser -Filter {title -eq "custod" -and locationNumber -notin $excludedLocations} | ForEach-Object {
    Add-ADGroupMember "SDK test print convert" $_.SamAccountName
}
```

Comment: The AD Powershell filter doesn't support `-in` and `-notin`. At least, not in the versions I'm aware of. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Answer (score 0):

I use a procedural method to build this kind of thing into an LDAPfilter, which is easier to construct than a load of `-or` statements, I feel.

```
$titles = @'
SECSCH
LTOSEC
???12
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# begin filter
## (&(samAccountType=805306368) is not really needed for Get-Aduser
$filter = "(&(samAccountType=805306368)(|"
# append each title
$titles | Foreach { $filter += "(title=$_)"}
# end filter
$filter += "))"

# filter = (&(samAccountType=805306368)(|(title=SECSCH)(title=SEC12)(title=LTOSEC)(title=???12)))
Get-Aduser -ldapfilter $filter
```

Notice I slipped a wildcard in the list. For example, that one will catch all titles exactly 5 chars long ending with "12". There may be shortcuts like that you can use in your environment.

If you use a wildcard query, but want to exclude some possible results, you can always add NOT clauses (make sure they're inside an AND clause, not inside the OR clause!):

`(&(samAccountType=805306368)(!title=SOP12)(|...`

Also remember `-searchbase` to start from specific OUs if that might help you use wildcards or just better target sets of users with less noise/filtering required.